# How to get click event within Google Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have `background.js` file, that works everywhere in browser.

I tried to write JS that listen click event then passes control to `content.js` script for handling.

I need to detect click on the page and after call custom method.

How can I do that?

I tried in `backgronud.js`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){

});
```

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (and perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: You need to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to interact with a web page (e.g. manipulate the DOM, listen to clicks on the page, etc.).

Comment: Are you wanting to detect `click` events within the web page? In a specific web page? All web pages? On a browser action button? Call what custom method? A custom method in a content script? In the background script? To do what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add custom scripts to a page you need to request permission on it and use [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: Can you fetch an sampe? I have content permissions